# Tomcat Error when I put the JSTL dependency. Using Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jstl

The error is simple: first I get the classic error, when trying to access the page via browser:

```
An Error Occurred:
javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:344)
```

Frist thing that comes in mind was the JSTL jar, them a put the code inside `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

After that I get that error, And I cannot start Tomcat any more

```
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:      org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/financeiro]]
```

If a remove de depedency from `pom.xml` I can start the tomcat again, but if a do thatt a get the `javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config` error when try to acesse the page

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>javaparaweb</groupId>
  <artifactId>financeiro</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Financeiro</name>
  <description>Gerenciamento Financeiro Pessoal</description>
  
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jvnet-nexus-releases</id>
        <name>jvnet-nexus-releases</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
        
</dependencies>
  
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
</project>
```

`web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         version="2.5"> 
  <display-name>financeiro</display-name>
  

 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
  
  
 
  
</web-app>
```

Comment: isn't there more in the error logging? And why do you think it is maven related? Do you not get this error when directly including it in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: And you have a weird mix of dependencies... java-ee 7 AND servlet api 2.5? That should be superfluous using java-ee7 (which is servelet 3.1 btw) And then a web-app 2.5 again? And using all that on tomcat? Weird... Maybe you should clean up that first and maybe the error goes away then

Comment: Hi, thx for the help, and witch one should a clean up?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have wrong location in your remote repositories. If you can't change the locaiton in `pom.xml` you can use the following [link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html#guide-to-installing-3rd-party-jars) to figure out how to install jar into the local repository. You have also remove `<repository>` tag from your project's `pom.xml`.

The central maven repositoty URL http://repo1.maven.org/ where you can download required jars.